# Insert a play button (image) over a video thumbnail in Jquery Mobile + Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, youtube

I have multiple thumbnails in a mySQL database generated for youtube videos using links like this for instance.

http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/1sIWez9HAbA/hqdefault.jpg

I am using Android Webview to show Jquery Mobile portion and the thumbnails are generated in Jquery Mobile.

Now i want to insert a play button in the middle for each and every thumbnail. The play button must disappear when anyone clicks on the thumbnail.

How can i do that? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

**Make your layout like this**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relVideo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgVideoThumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imgPlayVideo"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:src="@drawable/video_play_btn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am using Jquery Mobile and Android Webview to play youtube videos in the youtube app itself. I am just showing the thumbnail and when i click the thumbnail youtube app opens and the video plays. But the problem is to put a play button in that thumbnail. I have multiple thumbnail links stored in mySQL database and i have to add the button dynamically for each and every thumbnail i insert.